# Symfony2 API - Best way to import and save a CSV file

Tags: php, file, api, symfony, csv

I need to create an API that receives via `POST` a .csv file that in a second moment has to be saved to the DB.

This is how I wrote the function:

```
    /**
    * @Route("/importCSV", name = "import_csv")
    * @Method("POST")
    **/
    public function importCSVAction(Request $request) {

    if ($this->getRequest()->files) {
        $type = "csv";
        $filename = date('Ymd').'-'.$type.'-filename';
        $directory = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../Documents';

        $request = $this->get('request');
        $data = $request->getContent();

        try {
            $fs = new Filesystem();
            $fs->dumpFile($filename, $data);
            move_uploaded_file($filename, $directory);
        }
        catch(IOException $e) {
            return new Response ("File not saved!", 500, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        }

        return new Response($data);
    }
    else return new Response("Error!", 500, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
}
```

**1** One problem is that the file is saved under the `web` folder and not under `Documents` as I wanted. 
Also, how can I check if the file I'm importing is a .csv file?

**2** I searched on the web but I did not found many resources on this subject. 
I just want to know if this is generally a correct way to save the .csv file.

Thanks!

Comment: Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: You forget the filename on $directory.